# How can I set the  CNAME record on network solutions for my heroku app?

Tags: web-services, heroku, dns

I bought a domain name on network solutions. I have a working app at blooming-summer-8571.herokuapp.com. I want my domain name on network solutions to point to this app. So in the CNAME records. It has a box for alias, ttl, and a drop down menu for @ (none) or www . Then there is another option you can check (instead of the drop down menu) to fill out an other host name.

So which is the alias? Should I check other host name and put in the heroku app's url? This is all done under my DNS settings for the domain I purchased so I assume that I don't have to fill it out anywhere? The online resources I have found are rather unhelpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A CNAME (Canonical Name) record is only for domains that you can control and points the canonical name to the correct domain name. What you need to do is point your domain to your Heroku app by following the steps in the following: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

The article does state to use CNAME to point to blooming-summer-8571.herokuapp.com (cedar server)

Comment: I read that article, and it says to configure the CNAME to point the subdomain (Im assuming it is the domain I bought at network solutions) to the applicable Heroku hostname. But it doesnt say specifically how to do this.

Comment: Correct. There should be an option for a subdomain info and the alternate location.

Comment: but which is which? Do I check the first option or the second one (described above)? Is it www or @?

Comment: On Network Solutions there is 4 available spots to put information for CNAME. The first one is your Subdomain (alias ex: app.mydomain.com - app would be in this field), second is your TTL, third is if you want it to be part of your own domain, forth is for pointing it to another domain (this is where you will put your app location).

Answer (score 3):

I just went through the same thing.

1. Log in to Network Solutions (Select manage my domains when you log in)
2. Click "Manage" on the domain you want to point to Heroku
3. Click "Edit Advanced DNS Records"
4. Click "Edit A Records" and clear the IP addresses for "www" and "* (All Others)". Put 205.178.189.129 in for "@ (None)" then click continue
5. Click "Edit CName Records"
6. put "www" in for the Alias. And "YOURAPP.herokuapp.com" in for the "Other Host" field. Make sure the radio button for "Other Host" is selected. Then click continue.
7. *IF you get an error* claiming you already have an A record for www then log out of Network Solutions, log back in, and try again.

This will point www.YOURDOMAIN.com to YOURAPP.herokuapp.com

To make sure it worked (give it some time before checking) open up a terminal window and type :

```
host www.YOURDOMAIN.com
```

It should respond with something like ..

```
www.YOURDOMAIN.com is an alias for YOURAPP.herokuapp.com.
```

Resources:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#domain-precedence
http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-forward-your-network-solutions-domain-name-to-a-free-blog-service/

Comment: This worked for me.  Instead of pointing to 205.178.189.129 I instead pointed to 45.55.72.95, which is apparently a server hosted by github that auto redirects a naked domain to www.domain.com (https://help.newsy.co/domain).  Edit: netsol is garbage.

Comment: How do you remove that alias? I'm running into an issue where host responds with that the domain has an alias of a deleted heroku app. Where is that set? I've deleted all the DNS entries where I bought the website.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that this page is extremely helpful for this:

http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-forward-your-network-solutions-domain-name-to-a-free-blog-service/

Basically you just need to delete all your A records, and point the @ one to the IP 205.178.189.129. Then, as long as you have a valid CNAME record for 'www' (in the case of Heroku, it'd point to your app's heroku URL), Network Solutions will correctly forward all traffic to your www CNAME.