# When my CNAME record redirects to my heroku app, it says there is no such app.

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

My app works fine on tradespring.heroku.com (I think. Well I can see it perfectly anyways). So I entered a CNAME record that redirects my domain(tradespring.net) with alias www to tradespring.heroku.com. But then when I enter www.tradespring.net it says heroku app not found.

When I just enter tradespring.heroku.com it works fine though. It does automatically change it to https://tradespring.heroku.com though. Why doesnt it work through the CNAME

Comment: Also, you asked the same thing yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606109/how-can-i-set-the-cname-record-on-network-solutions-for-my-heroku-app... you must be kiding

Comment: sorry I will try and be more interactive with question answerers

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`heroku domains:add www.tradespring.net`

Comment: I kept skipping this step because the custom link already showed up in my Heroku app. Ran this and it started working! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

It is because the CNAME entry is redirecting to heroku but asking from "tradespring.net" for heroku. And that is ok, it should work this way. Now I supose you have to configure heroku in to respond request to your domain.

Here is the tutorial for heroku custom domains:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains